# How to switch between two databses, based on user request in Java web application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

I am using Spring restful web services in my project, here I have two categories of users

1) secondary (Student studying class between 6 to 10th)

2) inter (Student studying class between 11th and 12th).

In each URI, we specify the user type, for example see below:
(http://localhost:8080/TestProject/login/**secondary**/authenticate)

For above request, I need to fetch the data from 'secondary' d.b tables.

Similarly for other user type request, need to communicate with other d.b(Inter).

In 'DAO' class:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            getDataSource());
    jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(
                "SET SCHEMA " + **UriUtils.getSchema()**);
```

In above UriUtils.getSchema(), method returns the 'DataBase' name.

```
private DataSource getDataSource() {
    String db = UriUtils.getDataBaseName();
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context environmentContext = (Context) initialContext
                .lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup(db);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        logger.info(db + " resource is not available in server.xml file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

In Tomcat server I configured the connection pooling.

server.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        logAbandoned="true" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
        name="secondary" password="admin" removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="90" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=secondary"
        username="postgres" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        logAbandoned="true" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
        name="inter" password="admin" removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="90" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=inter"
        username="postgres" />
```

## context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="secondary" global="secondary"
    type="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<ResourceLink name="inter" global="inter"
    type="org.postgresql.Driver" />
```

Is loading the **datasource** object every time is a good practice ?

Please suggest if any better approach is available.

Comment: Normally, when using Spring, you would *inject* the DataSource into your DAO classes. In your case, you'd inject two of them, then select which one to use when constructing the `JdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

Is loading the datasource object every time is a good practice ?

> > NO, IMV.

Define two `datasources (secondaryDS, interDS)` as spring beans default to singleton, and inject corresponding `datasource` to `JDBCTemplate`class as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not loading database every time. Lookup operation is not loading database. It is OK perform lookup on every request. Also I do not see two databases in your sample. You have two data sources over one postgresql database. You can use one data source and perform `SET SCHEMA` on each client request for schema switching.